# Android PrintManager API doesn't work in Bluestacks

Tags: android, printing, android-4.4-kitkat, bluestacks

I use `PrintManager` to print a `html` content . Its work in real devices well. but in Bluestacks app get closed without any message even it doesn't say "Force close".
this is the print code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    // Get a PrintManager instance
                    android.print.PrintManager printManager = (android.print.PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

                    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = mWebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

                    // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
                    String jobName = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
                    PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
                }
```

the bluestacks os version is 4.4.2 .

```
[ro.build.version.release]: [4.4.2]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [19]
```

in debug mode its get the line `printManager.print()` but after that app get closed.

Comment: We have same issue, Did u got any solution for this ? 
Please help us to solve this issue :(

Comment: Not yet, we use remix OS instead

Comment: same here, cannot print/create a pdf using printmanager in BlueStacks